# Linha Pontilhada (Dotted/Dashed Line)

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou tentando criar uma linha de divisão em meu App conforme demonstrado abaixo.

***drawable/dotted.xml***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">

    <stroke
       android:color="#C7B299"
       android:dashWidth="10px"
       android:dashGap="10px"
       android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

***view.xml***:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted"
    android:layerType="software" />
```

Porém não está funcionando corretamente, ao invés de ficar uma linha pontilhada está ficando uma linha reta.

Alguém saberia me dizer o motivo?

Answer (score 2):

O que poderá estar a provocar isso é o uso da unidade `px` para as dimensões de `android:dashWidth` e `android:dashGap`.

Em dispositivos com tela de elevada densidade de pixeis é possível que 10 pixeis não sejam perceptíveis como um espaço, dando a ideia de que a linha é contínua.

Para que as dimensões sejam independentes da densidade da tela elas devem ser indicadas usando a unidade `dp`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">

    <stroke
       android:color="#C7B299"
       android:dashWidth="10dp"
       android:dashGap="10dp"
       android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```